# WebSocket and Redis results in hanging connection from pubsub and/or brpop

Tags: ruby, websocket, redis, publish-subscribe, eventmachine

I am issuing a Redis subscribe within WebSocket (WS).  When I receive the WS open, I thread the request and then instantiate the Redis client.  Within the open, I thread for Redis and issue the subscription.

This all works fine, until I receive an unexpected WS close.  At that point, the thread running the Redis subscription is gone.  If I issue an unsubscribe, I get a hang.  If I don't unsubscribe, I have left a phantom subscription that causes me trouble next go round.

Is there some way to delete a subscription once the thread that issued it has terminated?  I have noted that the Redis instance has a mon variable for that terminated thread.  Sample Ruby code is:

```
class Backend
  include MInit

  def initialize(app)
    setup
    @app = app
  end

  def run!(env)
    if Faye::WebSocket.websocket?(env)
      ws = Faye::WebSocket.new(env, [], ping: KEEPALIVE_TIME)
      ws_thread = Thread.fork(env) do
        credis = Redis.new(host: @redis_uri.host, port: @redis_uri.port, password: @redis_uri.password)

        ws.on :open do |event|
          channel = URI.parse(event.target.url).path[1..URI.parse(event.target.url).path.length]
          redis_thread = Thread.fork do
            credis.subscribe(channel) do |on|
              on.message do |message_channel, message|
                sent = ws.send(message)
              end
              on.unsubscribe do |message_channel|
                puts "Unsubscribe on channel:#{channel};"
              end
            end
          end
        end

        ws.on :message do |event|
          handoff(ws: ws, event: event)
        end

        ws.on :close do |event|
          # Hang occurs here
          unsubscribed = credis.unsubscribe(channel)
        end

        ws.on :error do |event|
          ws.close
        end

        # Return async Rack response
        ws.rack_response

      end
    end
  else
    @app.call(env)
  end

  private
  def handoff(ws: nil, event: nil, source: nil, message: nil)
    # processing
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix is rather simple once I really understood the problem.  The Redis thread actually still exists. But, Redis is hanging anyway because it is waiting for the thread to get control. To do that, the WS.close code needs to cede control by using EM.next_tick within the WS.close as follows:

```
ws.on :close do |event|
  EM.next_tick do
    # Hang occurs here
    unsubscribed = credis.unsubscribe(channel)
  end
end
```

Comment: Another approach you might try is to have Redis periodically publish to the topic some harmless message, forcing a _write_ to all subscriptions.  Any "phantom" subscriptions should then be cleared/closed, as Redis detects the errors from writing to a dead/closed peer.

Comment: @Castaglia Interesting. In my case, knowing the prior subscription failed to clear without knowing how to clear it, upon recovery I issued another subscription and continued processing.  This would publish messages to the same channel, both the phantom subscription and the newly live channel under the same name.  Would you expect that to also clear the phantom?  I ask because, over time, I ran into resource constraints in that scenario.

Comment: Ah, I think I see.  The subscription is tied to the TCP connection, and _that_ TCP connection is still there; it's the _thread_ on the client end which died, and thus "lost" the subscription, from the POV of the rest of the application.  Yes?  I wonder if doing an `UNSUBSCRIBE` (either specifying all of your channels, or none to unsubscribe from all of them) from that same TCP connection (to clear any phantom/lost/lingering subscriptions), then re-subscribing explicitly, might work.

Comment: @Castaglia  So, do you agree that the update and code I added will reliably kill the connection?  Seems to be working to me, so far, but, well, further testing and verification needed.  Thanks.

Comment: As there're no other means to get the connection ID, I can't think of a more elegant approach.  Maybe if you wanted to use the client's local address/port, rather than connection ID, for the `CLIENT KILL` command?  Otherwise, seems like a workable solution.

Comment: @Castaglia Yes, that is certainly as possible as using ID.  However, it'd be pretty much the same since, having gone through all the methods, it still seems to boil down to using CLIENT LIST to get the specific port for the specific connection that needs to be killed.  I think I will go ahead a post an issue to redis-rb about the need to present ID and address/port directly using a method.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a long comment to offer a workaround rather than a solution.

If it were my application, I would re-consider the design.

Openning a new Redis connection and a new thread for every websocket client is a rather big commitment of resources.

Just to clarify, each connection to Redis requires a TCP/IP socket (which is a limited resource) and memory. Threads should cost about 2Mib per thread for their reserved stack memory... so that 1K Redis connections and threads can incur about a 2Gib cost in memory.

This is in addition to the fact that the Redis server itself has a limited amount of connections it can usually accept (although, this is usually a question of price rather than a hard limit, since they're designed to scale).

It should be quite simple to re-adjust the design so a single thread and connection are serving all websocket clients, which would also allow for an easier `subscribe`/`unsubscribe` management.

This can either be performed using an internal per-process broadcasting system (such as implemented by [plezi.io](http://www.plezi.io)) or by using the Redis `subscribe`/`punsubscribe` commands.

Comment: I looked at plezi.io first.  In fact, I recently reviewed it to see if it had an unsubscribe fix.  It simply didn't suit my needs.  Yes, I do understand the burdens of the Redis connections, as I monitor them.  That is  one reason I was so focused on cleaning up the orphans.  Actually, within this process, I converted from PUBSUB to LPUSH/BRPOP, though it suffers from the same issue here, it is just easier to manage.  My final use case simply requires the design I've selected.  Thanks for the advice, however.

Comment: @R_G , I guess sometimes the design is out of our hands... I can only wish you good luck!  ...  P.S. ...  I didn't mean to push plezi and I apologize if it came out that way.

Comment: Certainly not!  I come here for advice and appreciate everyone's efforts!